# How can I mock a component's state for unit testing?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using enzyme, jest, sinon for unit testing. I would like to mock a components state and pass in a custom state before the component gets render. How can I achieve this?

My component starts off with some initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     sample: "hello"
   }
}
```

I want to overwrite the value of sample before render happens by mocking a fake state and before calling shallow().

Comment: *I want to overwrite the value of sample before render happens by mocking a fake state and before calling shallow()* - why?

Answer (score -1):

Call setState directly on the component?

Not 100% sure, but maybe...

```
const myComponent = <MyComponent {...props} />
myComponent.setState({ ...mockState })

const myShallowRenderedComponent = shallow(myComponent)
const instance = myShallowRenderedComponent .instance()
expect(instance.state).toEqual(mockState)
```

Comment: This solution will not work because the `myComponent` variable is an `Element` and does not expose a `setState` method. `myComponent` is not an instance of `MyComponent`. It is a description of the component to be created. You don't actually have a `React.Component` until the element is rendered/initialized by React. See example failure: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/319158/. More information on the difference is available here: https://medium.com/@fay_jai/react-elements-vs-react-components-vs-component-backing-instances-14d42729f62.